# Voting system/engine for customers?

Tags: voting, feedback

I'm talking about some web thing like http://uservoice.com/
Can you suggest any other similar service, web-site or may be (even better) a ready engine for deployment on own server?

Actually, the question more about systems, which can be installed on your own server.

Answer (score 2):

[UseResponse](http://www.useresponse.com), commercial (full sourcecode available on purchase), launching December 2011, with live demo available on [USWebStyle](http://support.uswebstyle.com) website. Fully customizable (design, functionality).

Types of feedback (idea, problem, question, thanks), vote types (positive and/or negative) are adjustable.

Installable on any PHP 5.2/5.3 hosting environment.

Answer (score 1):

[TenderApp](http://tenderapp.com/) seems to have a lot of the same features, but it's also SaaS.

[KBPublisher](http://www.kbpublisher.com/) can be installed on your server.

By the way, most of these SaaS systems like UserVoice will let you forward your own domain/subdomain to their service and apply custom branding, so the experience to your end user is very similar to being on your actual site.

Comment: Yes, but customizations are usual cost much.

Comment: KPPublisher is more like knowledge base/FAQ/documentation system. I.e. you (as developer) write articles.

Thanks for the reply.